# Edit Sharepoint Online metadata in a Word Add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, word

I am trying to get my head around developing a taskpane addin for Word that will allow my end users to get and set info from the document library. This area is a bit new to me so I've been working my way through the tutorials and documentation for the [Word JavaScript API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview?view=word-js-preview). It's mostly making sense to me but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to deal with the Sharepoint side of things.

Can anyone point me to some good resources?

Edit: looking more into this, it's looking like REST is the way to go with this. If there are any tutorials that focus on integrating the REST API with a task pane add in, it's beyond my google-fu to find them. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word already has this built-in. Under the View tab in the ribbon, there is a SharePoint button that will retrieve all additional metadata as defined in your columns for the particular library.

Comment: JFC I can't believe i missed that. SMH

Answer (score 1):

Just as Trevor said, if you are using Office 2016 and later version, you can find the SharePoint Properties button in View tab. It is like this in Office 365 word
[image]

Some information about it:https://sympmarc.com/2017/11/16/the-new-dip-the-sharepoint-properties-panel-arrives-in-word/